# Escaping "{{}}" auto-interpretation in a Script tag in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, handlebars.js

I am building a visual rendering of a database table and other webapp functionalities using node.js, express, mysql, bootstrap, and handlebars.

I have a pages.js file that render my internships.hbs file like so:

```
        res.render('internships', {
            user: req.user,
            jobs: req.internships

        });
```

later I will be accessing jobs in a script within my hbs file, and jobs is json that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    job_id: 1,
    company_name: 'Morgan Stanley',
    internship_title: '2021 Technology Summer Analyst Program',
    location: 'New York City',
    link: 'https://morganstanley.tal.net/vx/lang-en-GB/mobile-0/brand-2/xf-3786f0ce9359/candidate/so/pm/1/pl/1/opp/9768-2021-Technology-Summer-Analyst-Program-New-York/en-GB'  
  },
  {
    job_id: 2,
    company_name: 'Five Rings',
    internship_title: 'Software Developer Intern ',
    location: 'New York City',
    link: 'https://jobs.jobvite.com/fiverings/job/o1OAcfwl'
  },
  {
    job_id: 3,
    company_name: 'DRW',
    internship_title: 'Software Developer Intern',
    location: 'Chicago',
    link: 'https://drw.com/careers/job/1350323'
  }
]
```

As jobs is a json returned from a table in a database elsewhere, I want to render that table within hbs with a variable amount of rows in the table based on how many rows are in the db table. So I have a for-loop creating rows, and I am trying to fill the cells with the info from the json:

```
<script>
    var table = document.getElementById("test");

    var len = {{jobs.length}};

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

      // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the last position of the table:
      var row = table.insertRow();

      // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      var working = "{{jobs.0.company_name}}";
      cell1.innerHTML = working;
      cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2"; 
      cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
      cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    }
</script>
```

Ignoring cells 2-4, I would like cell 1 to access the company_name from json based on the i of the loop. So this code works, but of course it
[puts Morgan Stanley in the cell each time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQlAd.png) because i hard coded the "0" element into the string.

Instead, I would like to have instead it be {{jobs.i.company_name}}. When I replace working with
working and cell1 lines with:

```
 var desired = "jobs." + i + ".company_name";
      cell1.innerHTML = "{{" + desired + "}}";
```

I just get  [blank cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAGdW.png), no company name shows up.

If I put the curleys in the desired var declaration line,

```
var desired = "{{jobs" + "." + i + ".company_name}}";
```

it doesn't let me concatenate the +i part because it starts reading the curly expression right away and after the "jobs." part i get this error][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGqvY.png) saying it expects an identifier after the period and does not get to perform the i concatenation.

I need to figure out how to build a curley bracketed string statement with the i variable in the middle, 0, 1, or 2 based on the json i put earlier, without it attempting to resolve the curly braces before I've finished building the string.

Comment: Before you begin to solve the issue of outputting the `company_name`, I would urge you to rewrite your template so that it is using the templating language (Handlebars) to create your HTML. You shouldn't be setting the `.innerHTML` of elements. This is what Handlebars should be doing for you.

Comment: yeah good call, i kind of came to that conclusion as well. definitely a disconnect in my understanding of what handlebars is that I should remedy first

Answer (score 0):

To fix your concatenation try this:

```
var desired = "{{jobs." + [i] + ".company_name}}";
```